# Unable to retun multiple dicitonary sets in python

Tags: python, function, dictionary, return-value

I'm querying a REST API url & I'm trying to return all the dictionary sets, but only able to return one key pair. 
Dictionary Output in the print statement inside for loop is the expected output, when when returned only one set of key pair is appearing.
Expected Dictionary looks like:

```
    {'IncidentID': 'IM10265'}
    {'IncidentID': 'IM10266'}
    {'IncidentID': 'IM10267'}
    {'IncidentID': 'IM10268'}
```

Code:

```
    import json , requests
sm1 = requests.get('http://Rest Url', auth=('XX','YY'))
z = json.loads(sm1.text)

def get_im_list():
    incidentlist_access = z['content']
    for im_data in incidentlist_access:
        Access_imslist = im_data['Incident']
        print(Access_imslist)
        #print(type(Access_imslist))
        #return Access_imslist

data = get_im_list()
#print(data)
```

So when when I'm un-commentating

```
return Access_imslist & print(data)
```

I'm only receiving the output as:

```
{'IncidentID': 'IM10265'}
```

not the complete dictionary.

Comment: Hi @Oxxodome, do you expect the input and output as a list of dictionary?

Comment: Hi @Oxxodome. Welcome to SO! For clarity, could you post the complete response of the REST API and also indicate the expected output in the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you loop through the data, `Access_imslist` gets overwritten, so when you (presumably) `return Access_Imlist` it's only returning the last value.

You need to create a data structure outside of the for loop, add each bit of data to it, then return that instead. Something like:

```
def get_im_list():
    incident_data = []
    incidentlist_access = z['content']
    for im_data in incidentlist_access:
        incident_data.append(im_data['Incident'])
    return incident_data
```

hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

you need to define a variable list , and then append the `Access_imslist` values to that variable.
like this :

```
data = []
def get_im_list():
incidentlist_access = z['content']
for im_data in incidentlist_access:
    Access_imslist = im_data['Incident']
    data.append(Access_imslist)
print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks Dharmendra, it worked too but I used the other method posted, Thanks a lot again for your support